# Distance between data and curve

Tags: fitting

I have two datasets:

```
dataset1 = {{3514147200, 5.83}, {3514233600, 7.48}, {3514320000, 7.86}, {3514406400, 6.74}}
dataset2 = {{2407708800, 131.3}, {2407795200, 131.7}, {2407881600, 130.9}, {2407968000, 131}}
```

By down sampling to get the datasets to be the same "length", I know that there is a correlation of approximately 0.95 between the two datasets.

I have created a **very large** polynomial from `dataset2` to approximate `dataset1`.

```
polynomial[x_] := -1.19937*10^11 - 16.2653 x - 9.10704*10^-10 x^2 + 4.74474*10^-19 x^3 + ...
```

When `polynomial` and `dataset1` are plotted together, I can see that the polynomial is close to the data. I am looking for a way to measure the "*distance*" between the dataset and the polynomial. I tried using `KolmogorovSmirnovTest` but it wasn't much help, any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of data you have?  "Dataset" in itself is not descriptive.

Comment: I will add portions of the data to show what they are like.

Comment: Another thing you might want to clarify is what you mean by "distance".  If you are asking about what is a good distance measure, it probably depends on the applications you have in mind, and it's not a question about Mathematica.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/ is likely a better place to ask.  If you already know what distance measure you need, then asking about how to compute it is appropriate here.

Comment: I don't mind which distance measure is used, I just want a way to quantify the distance between the two using Mathematica or to see how likely it is that this particular data comes from the polynomial.

Comment: So you have $(x_i,y_i)$ pairs that could be considered to approximate a function.  If the domain of the two curves is the same, you could build an interpolation function from them (`Interpolation`) and `NIntegrate` the square of their difference.

Comment: just fyi a high order polynomial is usually a terrible way to approximate data. You will tend to hit the points well and deviate wildly in between.

Comment: Have you considered functions like [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fit.html) and [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)?

Answer (score 2):

```
dataset1 = Table[{x1[n], y1[n]}, {n, 5}];

poly2[x_] = a*x^2 + b*x + c;

rms1 = Norm[(poly2 /@ dataset1[[All, 1]]) - dataset1[[All, 2]]]/
   Sqrt[Length[dataset1]];

rms2 = RootMeanSquare[(poly2 /@ dataset1[[All, 1]]) - 
    dataset1[[All, 2]]];

(rms1 // ComplexExpand) == rms2
```

> True